# iterate column value based on repeating range in next column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet that represents a network switch. The first row for each switch are the odd ports, beneath that are the destination ports for each of those switch ports, beneath that are the even ports, and beneath that are the destination ports for each of the even ports. So, 4 rows of information, the first and third representing switch ports, the second and third rows are their respective destinations. I have manipulated this data into columns, and as the ports repeat (moving to the next switch, ports 1-36) I need to iterate the name of these switches as we move down the column, so next time it sees port 1, it needs to pull the name of the new switch for all rows that belong to that switch and add the name in the new column.

I've got everything squared away with the exception figuring out how to have pandas know that the series has started over, and it's time to iterate to this new switch name, which is pulled from the same spreadsheet.

I don't even know where to begin and haven't found a good example. Current state for first three lines:

```
0    1     Rx  LEAF A   Px  
1    3     Rx  LEAF B   Px  
2    5     Rx  LEAF A   Px
```

When this series repeats and you see a '1' in the second column again, I need to iterate to the next switch name, we'll call the switch list: A1, A2, A3, for example, so desired output for first switch:

```
0    A1  1     Rx  LEAF A   Px  
1    A1  3     Rx  LEAF B   Px  
2    A1  5     Rx  LEAF A   Px
```

Second switch:

```
0    A2  1     Rx  LEAF A   Px  
1    A2  3     Rx  LEAF B   Px  
2    A2  5     Rx  LEAF A   Px
```

Third Switch:

```
0    A3  1     R1  LEAF A   Px  
1    A3  3     R1  LEAF B   Px  
2    A3  5     R6  LEAF A   Px
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just beginning with Python and Pandas, and have hit a roadblock, even after a couple days of search.Thanks!

Comment: `df['col'] == 1` will give you a boolean series T, F, F, ..., T, F ... and so on. Taking the cumulative sum of that series will give you 1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2, ... and so on (since T ~ 1 and F ~ 0). Then you can map those labels 1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2... to the new labels (e.g. A1, A2, etc). Alternatively you can count how many times `df['col'] == 1` and assign a new label to each row where that happens, and then forward fill.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've done the boolean series and am now working on mapping the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5], 'col2':['Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx','Rx'], 'col3':['LEAF A', 'LEAF B', 'LEAF C','LEAF A', 'LEAF B', 'LEAF C','LEAF A', 'LEAF B', 'LEAF C'], 'col4': ['Px', 'Px', 'Px','Px', 'Px', 'Px','Px', 'Px', 'Px']})

i = 0
counter = 0
s = []

while i < len(df):
    counter += 1
    for j in range(0,3):
        if counter == 1:
            s.append('A1')
            i += 1
        elif counter == 2:
            s.append('A2')
            i += 1
        elif counter == 3:
            s.append('A3')
            i += 1
    if counter == 3:
        counter = 0
    else:
        pass

df['Switch'] = s

print(df)

   col1 col2    col3 col4 Switch
0     1   Rx  LEAF A   Px     A1
1     3   Rx  LEAF B   Px     A1
2     5   Rx  LEAF C   Px     A1
3     1   Rx  LEAF A   Px     A2
4     3   Rx  LEAF B   Px     A2
5     5   Rx  LEAF C   Px     A2
6     1   Rx  LEAF A   Px     A3
7     3   Rx  LEAF B   Px     A3
8     5   Rx  LEAF C   Px     A3
```

This is your desired output right? Let me know if this works.

Cheers :D

Comment: OK, The issue is that my use case is actually more complex, and instead of running 1,3,5, it's actually 1-36 with a couple of named ports. The code is recognizing any 1, 2, or 3 in the list and adding the appropriate switch name, so for port 20, it's counting that as a 2, and appending 'A2', even though it should still be 'A1' until the port count gets back to port 1 again. ideas? :) We're definitely getting closer...

Comment: Wait... wouldn't i just use the Boolean example above, and then use that count as the 1,2,3 and then your code would do the mapping? Sorry, I'm completely new to this..

Comment: Use the number of max switches as the length of the appended category range (0-36). 0 through 36.

Comment: As long as you want to tag the first 36 entry as A1 and second as 36 as A2 just copy the code above change three max value for iteration and add  necessary loops if categories are greater than 3.